# Keep two modules with doctrine entities independent

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I work on two ZF2 modules in the same project who both contains severals doctrine2 entities. Theses entities have relations between modules.

Eg:

Module1\Entities\Entity1 
has a Many to One relation with 
Module2\Entities\Entity2

Is there a way to keep the two modules independents?  I mean, if Module1 is the core module, I'd like to desactivate the module2 without conflict.

Found nothing about that.

Thanx !

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine 2 has what they call a [resolveTargetEntityListener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html):  which might serve your purposes.  Symfony 2 has an [implementation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) for it: It's possible that ZF2 has one as well.

But the bottom line is that you designed a dependency between two bundles and it's unreasonable to expect to be able to remove one.  Your best bet would probably be to remove the relation between the two entities and just use two queries to grab what you need.  Possibly use event listeners to communicate between the bundles.